# Laravel Pattern Filters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following code in laravel concerning Pattern Filters but its not working. The problem is with the WILDCARD. If i use only `profile` without the wildcard, it works perfectly but with it, there is `"NotFoundHttpException"` exception::

```
Route::when('profile/*', 'christmas');
Route::get('/profile', function(){
        return "This is my profile";
    }
);

/: Filter
Route::filter('christmas',function(){
    //if(date('d/m/y') == '12/12/84'){
    if(false){
        return View::make('christmas');
    }
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your other routes that you're trying to get are defined as well, for example:

```
Route::when('profile/*', 'christmas');

Route::get('/profile', function(){
        return "This is my profile";
    }
);
Route::get('/profile/1', function(){
        return "This is my profile 1";
    }
);
Route::get('/profile/2', function(){
        return "This is my profile 2";
    }
);
etc...
```